# PHP Multiple form tokens

Tags: php, forms, captcha

I am considering generating a unique form token and storing it in a session, and embedding it as a hidden input in my forms.

Could I make this work for pages containing multiple forms, is it still safe to use the same token for each form?

I'm looking to detect bot requests on my website, can these form tokens really safely replace CAPTCHAs?

Comment: Such tokens are not for replacing captchas but for preventing XSS (or CSRF? or both? not sure about this) [This article regarding PHP form security](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/2.html) is worth reading I guess.

Comment: I'm only using captchas to stop broswer&bots, auto-submitting a form multiple times. and if they tried to submit the same token my script would flag up an error.

Comment: Well, tokens help to prevent manually created HTTP POST request from being accepted. Captachas help to prevent automatic form submission at your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, these tokens cannot replace captchas because these things serve different purposes.

From your confusion with tokens and captchas I suppose that you don't really understand these tokens. Are you sure you need separate tokens for every form? May be one token per session would be enough?

Comment: All I want to do is stop a BOT auto-submitting a form once every minute.

Comment: @Juddling well tokens won't help you. Good CAPTCHA would.

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely fine to use the same token for all forms. Even on different pages. It's OK to generate the token in the very beginning of your users session and stick with it.
Also those tokens only protect you/your users from Cross-site request forgery.

For protection from bots you still need Captchas or something equal.